# Curl: Which API calls are involved in this curl statement?

Tags: c, curl

I'm trying to figure out what is going on "under the hood" in terms of curl API calls when this curl command is executed:

```
curl "http://someURL" --header "apikey:someNumbers" --header "Content-Type:audio/x-wav"
    --header "lngCode:en_US" --data-binary @audiofile.wav
```

In other words: how do you do the above in C using the curl API ?

Besides posting this binary file to a remote server, I'm also interested in how you can use curl to parse the response from the server (the server analyzes the audio file and returns some results back to the client).

Comment: curl.exe is open source, so you could just look up the answer yourself.

Comment: @Remy: Or I could ask somebody who has more experience with curl than I do, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command:

```
curl "http://someURL" --header "apikey:someNumbers" --header "Content-Type:audio/x-wav" --header "lngCode:en_US" --data-binary @audiofile.wav
```

Roughly translates to the following libcurl function calls:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://someURL");

curl_slist *headers = curl_slist_append(NULL, "apikey:someNumbers");
curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type:audio/x-wav");
curl_slist_append(headers, "lngCode:en_US");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

// read content of "audiofile.wav" into a memory buffer, then...
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, (char*) <pointer to memory buffer>);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t) <size of memory buffer>);

curl_easy_perform(curl);

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
curl_slist_free_all(headers);

curl_global_cleanup();
```